# What is then method for binomial Logistic regression parameter estimation in MATLAB `glmfit`

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to do multinomial logistic regression using iterative re-weighted least square for estimating model parameters.

I'm using linear least square for estimate model parameter in binomial logistic regression and I am not sure about how MATLAB's `glmfit` does it.

What is method for estimate parameters in `glmfit` function?

Comment: I dont know, but I'd start by reading the refferences provided by Mathworks. Also, binomial or multinomial? Or Both?